# MFC add Typelib or ActiveX for OPOS

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, typelib, opos

So at work I have been working for a few months on a OPOS driver for a few different things. I didn't create the project, but I have taken it over and am the only one developing it. So today I got curious about the way that it was done and I think that it may have started off on the wrong foot. I had to do a little bit of digging to find out that it uses the OPOS drivers from a company called MCS (Monroe Consulting Services) I downloaded 1.13 and installed the MSI version. I fired up VS created a new mfc dll. I then went to add a class. This is where I am confused.

It doesn't matter if i choose Typelib or ActiveX it usually gives me the same list of interfaces that I can add/extend from(with one exception that comes to mind with MSR it has an events interface that I can extend) And they both make the same header file (in the case with msr it is COPOSMSR.h) but one extends CCmdTarget, and the other extends CWnd. This is my first question. Which should I choose? what is a typelib/ what is a ActiveX component and how do they differ from one another.

The one i've been working on extends CCmdTarget. For the life of me I can not figure out how the driver knows to use one of the files (USNMSRRFID) but that is where all the development went into. (I broke it up a bit so it wasn't just one huge file) But that file doesn't extend COPOSMSR..it extends CCmdTarget as well. The only time i see anything mention the USN file is in MSRRFID.idl (which confuses me even more) Any one have clarity for this?

Part of me thinks this could make a very big impact when it comes time to deploy. A few of the test apps that have been written that make use of this driver require a somewhat confusing setup process that involves registering different drivers, copying files into a specific folder, setting up the registry and so forth. I think that if i can get a grip on what this all means and how to make a nice application that extends one of these OPOS devices properly that I could save my self further grief in the future.

Any tips or pointers??? Sorry if it is a newb question..but i am new to C++. I started with Java then moved to C# so some of this stuff is WAY over my head....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well so I've done TONS of digging, and it is like searching for dinosaurs. Not easy, and hard to find. I will end up writing a nice little how to on this, but for now I will put up my findings. Although I still don't have this 100% i know I am close.

Turns out the typelib and activeX things are not a big concern but come into play after you've gotten started. ActiveX is for Control objects, and Typelib is for the Service Object. The most important thing is to get started correctly. I found a article on some Chinese website that offers some OK tips after figuring out the translation errors. To start with you will want to make a C++ project with Automation. It can be ATL or MFC. My preference is MFC. In the UPOS 1.13 pdf (or newer) in Appendix A section 8 it describes the responsibilities of the Service object. It has the main methods you need to implement. There are 16 methods you have to add, and at least 4 methods that get/set the properties for your OPOS device.

So to get started you will need to open up the add class wizard (for MFC classes) and click Add MFC class. You wil want your base class to be CCmdTarget. Come up with a classy Class name (I chose PinpadSOCPP) Then in the automation radio buttons select Creatable by type ID. It should fill in your type id as [Project Name].[Class name] so mine was PinpadSO.PinpadSOCPP. hit finish. This makes a nice interface file that you can use Class view to add methods and so forth to it.

As for adding the methods there are 2 things to note about this, and one of them I haven't figured out 100% yet. The first is that you have to implement all the methods in that section with the correct parameters and return values. Most of them return LONG (32bit signed number). and the 2 most common parameters are LONG and BSTR. (there is the occasional pointers for when you have "out" parameters) This is the part that I think that I am currently failing as I don't know if I have them all implemented correctly and that is why I am getting error 104/305 (which from the Chinese article says that I am missing something from my methods) I'm not sure if it is case sensitive, and I'm not sure of the 7 properties that look to need to have get/set which ones need to be implemented because the MSR SO that i am working on from work doesn't use them all and that SO is working. The other is that after you implement the base OPOS methods you have to also implement the extra methods from your specific OPOS device. Since I am doing PINPad there are 6 additional methods I have to implement.

Now this is a lot of time consuming work because you have to open up class view, navigate to the name of your project class. Expand it and go to the Interface portion. My Project name is PinpadSO, and the file that I am implementing this in is PinpadSOCPP (which means the interface name is IPinpadSOCPP) right click on IPinpadSOCPP and click add > add method. This brings you to a 2 step process. You fill in your return value, name of your function, add in all your parameters. Hit next and fill out some help string info (if you want) and hit finish. Now after you do that 20+ times it gets old and slow...and if you are like me you type Computer instead of Compute and flip flop letters, or forget to hit add on all your parameters. A person could make a nice little program to edit the 3 files that get changed each time you add a method and that would speed it up considerably. If you make a mistake you will need to open up `[project name].idl`, `[class name].h`, and `[class name].cpp` those are the 3 files that get the methods added to it directly. I recommend not making a mistake.

so now that all that hard work is out of the way. Compile your program. If you want to save your self an extra step you could turn on Auto Register in the linker project settings (NOTE: if you do that you'll need to run Visual Studio as admin if you program in vista or higher) this would save you of having to open a command window (admin) navigate to your DLL and use the command regsvr32 on that DLL. Nice thing is that you don't have to do that over and over again, just the once will do. I have no hard facts that it works like that every time but the MSR SO that I am working on, I'll make changes to it, compile it, then open up my OPOS tester program and the changes have taken affect.

After that you need to make your registry additions. navigate to HKLM\software\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS
(<strike>NOTE if you have a x64 machine you'll do this twice. One there, and again at HKLM\software\Wow6432Node\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS</strike> )

You'll need to add a Key for whatever OPOS device you are working with. I am making a pinpad SO so I made a Key called PINPad (check your UPOS document to see what name you should give it) Lastly choose a name for your device. I chose the model type of the from the vendor as my device name (C100) and made a sub key in PINPad. The default REG_SZ value needs to be your registered SO Device TypeID. in my case it is PinpadSO.PinpadSOCPP

if you don't have a OPOS test program (which I just made my own as a console program) then you can use the Microsoft OPOS test app (I couldn't get it to work on my x64 machine...but maybe you'll have better luck with it) If you do decide to make your own OPOS test app make sure you compile it for x86 machines (even if you have x64) OPOS does not like x64 for some reason (probably the pointers length I'd assume)..at any rate. Once you got it all setup run your test app (for my case I am just running `OPOSPinpadClass pin = new OPOSPinpadClass(); Console.WriteLine(pin.Open("C100"));` and hope for 0 :)

I am currently getting 104 (E_NOSERVICE)..and like i said before i think it is because I don't have all my methods correct. If that turns out to be the case I'll edit this response, or I'll report back and say what it really was.
Anywho, i hope this helps anyone else who decides they want to make their own SO. Good luck

**UPDATE**

OPOS checks a couple of properties when you call the Open command. One of the properties that is a must to implement is the in the GetPropertyNumber, and it is `PIDX_ServiceObjectVersion`. You will need to set this number to return `(1000000 * majorVersion) + (1000 * minorVersion) + revision` since I am making a OPOS 1.13 compatible SO my returned ServiceObjectVersion is 1013000. You will also want to implement 3 properties in GetPropertyString:

- `PIDX_DeviceDescription`
- `PIDX_DeviceName`
- `PIDX_ServiceObjectDescription`

For all other values you can return a empty string or 0 until you start hooking all those things up.

As a side note if you don't want to make it in C++ you don't have to. You can make it in any language that you can write a ActiveX object in (such as a COM visible .NET class library)